# The difference between == and equals() :leetcode242. Valid Anagram, a

Tags: java, character, operators, equals

I used a foolish method to solve this problem.
The program seems right but I failed the last test case.

**I replaced "sc.get(c)!= tc.get(c)" with "!sc.get(c).equals(tc.get(c))" and then I passed.**
What's wrong with my code and I want to know more details! TX!! :)

Here are my codes:

```
 public boolean isAnagram(String s, String t) {
    if(s.length()!=t.length()){
        return false;
    }
    HashMap<Character,Integer> sc = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<Character,Integer> tc = new HashMap<>();

    for(char c : s.toCharArray()){
        if(sc.keySet().contains(c)){
            sc.put(c,sc.get(c)+1);
        }else{
            sc.put(c,1);
        }
    }

    for(char c : t.toCharArray()){
        if(tc.keySet().contains(c)){
            tc.put(c,tc.get(c)+1);
        }else{
            tc.put(c,1);
        }
    }

    for(char c : sc.keySet()){
        if(!tc.keySet().contains(c) || sc.get(c)!= tc.get(c)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    for(char c : tc.keySet()){
        if(!sc.keySet().contains(c)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WKKF.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between == and equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-and-equals-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

`sc.get(c)` and `tc.get(c)` returns an Integer, not an int.
Since Integer is a wrapper class and not a primitive type, we have to use .equals() for content comparison. 
`sc.get(c) == tc.get(c)` checks if the memory address of the object returned by `sc.get(c)` is equal to that of `tc.get(c)`.

Comment: Yeah,I got it! Thanks for your ANSWER :)